# Angular 2 app component array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a string variable which is the name of a component. I need to pass this variable to another object property but as the component object and not as a string.

So, is there a global array that stores all the components for the app that I can access? Something like this;

```
let componentName = 'myComponentName';
componentsArray[componentName];
```

Or, can I cast the variable to type :Component?

Edited...

I am creating a routing configuration;

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
  path: 'home',
  component: componentName
  },
  {
    path: 'services',
    component: componentName
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: componentName
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: componentName
  }
];
```

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes, the `declarations` property in `@Component` decorator at `app.module` holds all the components you use in the app. May be you can look into that

Comment: And, no. casting a string into component type will not work.

Comment: What are you doing with this array? perhaps we can suggested an alternative implementation. Yours is a very unintuitive design given the way Angular2 is built.

Comment: I'm creating routes dynamically so I am assigning the variable to the "component" property of the route which has to be of type component. The variable is a string pulled from the db

Comment: I'd don't see why you would need to store the component in an object. You can just use a string to build your route using `ActivatedRoute` and handling the new route in your routing configuration.

Comment: I thought ActivatedRoute was only accessible within the component that app is currently rendering. In which case I need to tell the routing config which component to use, right?

Answer (score 0):

The data structure you are describe is not commonly used in Angular2. I suspect that you wish to pass the components around you application using this array as you would store elements in an array to pass them around in `PHP`.

Angular solves this problem differently, It has a variety of tools to show and hide components. Such as the [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html) directive `[hidden]` (don't use this over `*ngIf` unless you can explain why), and most importantly, the built in [Router](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html). Learning these will be a bit of an investment, but once you have them you'll benefit from way better performance.